# Ext.Ajax.request always fails

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to access any web resource via Ext.Ajax.request but it is always failing, for example I have GlassFish Server on my localhost at port 4848 and when I try to access it the request fails,I've tried other urls but with no success.
this is my code:

```
`items:[ 
        {
         id : 'button1',
         xtype : 'button',
         text : 'click',
         listeners: {
             click : function(btn){
                         Ext.Ajax.request({
                             method : 'GET',
                             url : 'http://localhost:4848',
                             success : function(){
                                          alert('success');
                                       },
                             failure : function(){
                                          alert('fail');
                                       }
                         });
             }
        }
]`
```

Comment: I'm only familiar with .Net web resource, but I can give you some advice: make sure you host the web resource first before running ExtJS, and config it to properly return the request to client-side. Also use the right Ajax request method (POST, GET) and pass the correct parameter.

Comment: I bet your js files are not server from the same port (80, maybe?). That makes your request cross domain, and cross domain AJAX requests are restricted.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should firstly specify a file after localhost.